# NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x00007fffe712ed20> while creating Users migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, faker

I'm creating a basic Users migration and I'm trying to seed it with the Faker gem and when I do rake db:repopulate (which is db:drop, db:create, db:migrate, db:seed) it keeps failing at db:seed. I'm getting an NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for #, the thing is it seems to create one User but then it fails and i can seem to understand why.. I've done the same in a similar project and haven't got this error and I've checked similar questions and haven't been able to fix it.

I first tought it was the name that might cause problem in both the migration and the tasks/db.rake so i fixed it but it didn't change, then i tried using migration convention's name but didn't work as well.

20191013045256_create_users.rb:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email                
      t.string :encrypted_password 
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_10_13_045256) do

  create_table "users", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "encrypted_password"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

tasks/db.rake:

```
require 'faker'
require 'bcrypt'

namespace :db do
  desc "Drop, create, migrate, seed and repopulate with sample data"
  task repopulate: [:drop, :create, :migrate, :seed, :fakeit] do
  puts "Done"
end

  desc "TODO"
  task fakeit: :environment do
    10.times do
      CreateUsers.create!(
        email: Faker::Internet.email,
        encrypted_password: BCrypt::Password.create(Faker::Internet.password)
      )
  end
end
end
```

I'm expecting to create 10 users for the users migration in my database but instead I'm getting this NoMethodError: undefined method `create!'

Comment: `User.create!` instead? What is `CreateUsers`? A service?

Comment: I've tried and still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error message `NoMethodError: undefined method 'create!' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x00007fffe712ed20>` denotes that you're trying to call the `create!` method on your migration, and not on the `User` model.

The migration file's task is to simply create the required table in your database. In this scenario, you want to populate the records for the `User` model which were created by the migration file. So you'll have to cal the `create!` method on the generated model and not the migration. Please change the `CreateUsers.create!` line to `User.create!(<your params>)`. That should work.

Note: Please run `rake db:migrate` after writing the migration in case you haven't (You probably have done that already since the `users` table appears in the schema).

Comment: by using devise and deleting the validatable on the user model i've been able to db:repopulate and by changing to User.create too of course.. thanks a lot!